# How to get Data of last 7 days

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I am trying to get data of the last 7 days but my code is not working. Getting "DATEADD function does not exist".

I have a date in this format: `2019-03-05T10:59:09.2996542+00:00`

```
SELECT *
FROM finaltest1
WHERE CAST(Date AS DATE) > DATEADD(DAY, -7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) ;
```

Comment: which data type is your column Date ????

Answer (score 2):

`DATEADD` is SQL, the MySQL equivalent is [`DATE_ADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) (or to subtract, [`DATE_SUB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)). The parameters are different too, the first is the date value and the second the interval of time you want to add. Also note that in MySQL, the `GETDATE` equivalent is [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate). For your query, this should work, assuming your `Date` column is in a valid format:

```
SELECT *
    FROM finaltest1
    WHERE CAST(Date AS DATE) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: its work but i have a very large dataset  it work too slow any alternative.

Comment: @A500010 this is about as simple as it can get. You could consider adding a `STORED` [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) with the value `CAST(Date AS DATE)` and then placing an index on that and using it in the query. Also I'm not sure if MySQL is smart enough not to do the `DATE_SUB` calculation for every row; if you can set a variable to the value e.g. `SET @date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);` and then use the variable in the where clause instead that might speed things up too.